# How to make angular checkbox checked when a function call angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an HTML like this for checkbox and my function

```
<mat-checkbox 
  [checked]="uncheckrx" 
  (change)="onClickExpandRx($event.checked)">
  Rx
</mat-checkbox>

<button 
  class="btn btn-default" 
  id="cancelConfirmForDelete" 
  (click)="cancelConfirmDelete()" 
  translate>
  Cancel
</button>
```

When clicking the button I need to make the checkbox checked. I am using angular 6

Answer (score 1):

Since you're binding to `uncheckrx` on your mat-checkbox, you can simply set that to `true` inside the `cancelConfirmDelete` method and that should do the trick.

Just implement your functions like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'checkbox-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['checkbox-overview-example.css'],
})
export class CheckboxOverviewExample {
  uncheckrx;

  onClickExpandRx(checked) {
    this.uncheckrx = checked;
  }

  cancelConfirmDelete() {
    this.uncheckrx = true;
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/check-mat-checkbox-on-button-click?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.ts) for your ref.

Comment: This is how I did. Somehow it is not working for me. Thank you

Comment: Can you please fork my StackBlitz, update it with your implementation and then post it so that I could have a look.

Comment: @ChanakaAmarasinghe, your StackBlitz implementation works. What exactly is the issue? Can you please highlight that.

Comment: Please, use "Angular way". [(ngModel)]. The guys that created angular material will thanks you don't make the thing in an old way

Comment: @Eliseo, `mat-checkbox` accepts a `checked` `@Input` property that the OP is binding to in their implementation. And I'm suggesting to change it in the `cancelConfirmDelete` method which will eventually change the `checked` state of the mat-checkbox. Would you please comment on why is this **NOT** an Angular way to doing this? I kinda lost you there.

Comment: @SiddAjmera, forget my stupit comment, it's only I get nervious when see [checked]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a ngModel binding like:

```
<mat-checkbox
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    name="test">THIS IS A CHECKBOX</mat-checkbox>
```

Set in your component/container the value to "true", for example in your button click function.
See more at https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox

Comment: This is the code example ^^. <button (click)="clickMe()">Set checkbox to true</button>  and in your component you create a function like "clickMe() { this.value = true; }

Answer (score 0):

Create ngModel binding to switch checked status

```
<mat-checkbox  [(ngModel)]="isOtherChecked">
      Other (please specify):
    </mat-checkbox>
```

TS

```
export class AppComponent {

  isChecked:boolean = false;

dropdownChangeEvent(event: any) {    
  this.isChecked = true;
}
```

}